# SQL query to show change history of data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in a SQL Server database which stores historical data on daily basis. The structure is shown below:

```
UploadDate    TypeID    Value1   Value2
-------------------------------------------
2012-01-08    1         NEG      1998-02-05
2012-01-08    2         NEG      1999-02-09
2012-01-08    3         STABLE   1997-02-06
2012-02-08    1         NEG      1998-02-05
2012-02-08    2         NEG      1999-02-09
2012-03-08    1         POS      2012-03-08
2012-03-08    2         STABLE   2012-01-08
```

As you can see above for the `TypeID` 1 & 2, `Value1` and `Value2` has changed on 2012-03-08

My requirement is such that I have to show only those rows which have changed from previous values.

In this case since `TypeID` 1 & 2 have changed than it should show the current and most nearest previous value. And for `TypeID` 3 since it has not changed, it will will only show the most current values. The result set would look something like below:

```
UploadDate    TypeID    Value1   Value2
-------------------------------------------
2012-01-08    3         STABLE   1997-02-06
2012-02-08    1         NEG      1998-02-05
2012-02-08    2         NEG      1999-02-09
2012-03-08    1         POS      2012-03-08
2012-03-08    2         STABLE   2012-01-08
```

Any idea how I can tackle this using SQL?

Comment: still not clear what you want dude?

Comment: Something is missing... What is the criteria to exclude the first two rows?

Comment: The criteria is such that only to show latest changes happening to particular typeID from previous values.

Comment: Is (CONVERT(TEXT,TypeID) + Value1) a unique identifier?

Comment: Please refer to my question again in bold.

Comment: @Gregology it can be, but I have to cater for Value2 as well.

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović wea is your answer? I was about to try it.

Comment: I've deleted it because it didn't handle a case when value would be restored down the line.

Comment: And brought it back to life but much humbler than it originally was. I'll try to get a solution without self-join after a sleep.

Comment: Thanks @Bat_Programmer. I was after same stuff too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uninspired version uses self-join on ordered set to check the value of chronologically previous row of the same typeid. If there is no previous row or values are different the row is output.

```
; with numbered as (
  select *,
         row_number() over (order by typeid, uploaddate) rn
    from table1
)
select n1.*
  from numbered n1
  left join numbered n2
    on n1.TypeID = n2.TypeID
   and n1.rn + 1 = n2.rn
 where (n2.rn is null 
    or n1.value1 <> n2.value1
    or n1.value2 <> n2.value2)
 order by typeid, uploaddate
```

[Here is Sql Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5de57/6).

**UPDATE**: another variant which does not require self-join but does require group by. Each timeline of same typeid, value1 and value2 are given unique group_number which is used later to extract max(uploaddate) for the group.

```
; with numbered as (
  select *,
         row_number() over (order by typeid, uploaddate)
       - row_number() over (partition by typeid, value1, value2 
                            order by uploaddate) group_number
    from table1
)
select max(uploaddate) uploaddate, typeid, value1, value2
  from numbered
group by typeid, value1, value2, group_number
order by typeid, uploaddate
```

[Another Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5de57/16).

Comment: Wow..this is amazing stuff. Just exactly what I wanted. Thanks alot NIkola

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer You're welcome. I'll still try to produce simpler solution tomorrow; if I succeed I'll let you know.

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer Alright, here is another version. Not that you need it but i really wanted to do this that way.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, you are a super star. You are the man. That is amazing stuff indeed. Thanks, Guru!