# Access SQL query to show change history of data

Tags: sql, ms-access

(Question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854673/sql-query-to-show-change-history-of-data) except that mine is 1-in Access, not SQL Server, and    2-only checking one column for change.)

Here is sample data of products (SKU), dates they were purchased, and the price at time of purchase:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
|      SKU       | Unit_Price |  Date_Due  |
+----------------+------------+------------+
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $13.00     | 11/2/2012  |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $13.00     | 10/19/2012 |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $13.00     | 9/28/2012  |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $10.50     | 9/21/2012  |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $13.00     | 8/27/2012  |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $13.00     | 7/4/2012   |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $12.50     | 6/19/2012  |
| BHM1700NDACSTA | $14.50     | 10/27/2012 |
| BHM1700NDACSTA | $14.73     | 9/29/2012  |
| BHM1700NDACSTA | $14.73     | 8/23/2012  |
| BHM1700NDACSTA | $14.50     | 6/20/2012  |
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

I only want to see one price for any given date range, so a given product was purchased multiple times at the same price, I only want to see the FIRST date for that product for that price:

Sample output would be as follows:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
|      SKU       | Unit_Price |  Date_Due  |
+----------------+------------+------------+
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $13.00     | 9/28/2012  |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $10.50     | 9/21/2012  |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $13.00     | 7/4/2012   |
| BHM1200NBACSTA | $12.50     | 6/19/2012  |
| BHM1700NDACSTA | $14.50     | 10/27/2012 |
| BHM1700NDACSTA | $14.73     | 8/23/2012  |
| BHM1700NDACSTA | $14.50     | 6/20/2012  |
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

(Notice that the price may go up, down, and then up.  I don't merely want a unique set of price for each product, but rather a unique set for each contiguous date range.)

So far, I have used:

```
SELECT hbp1.SKU, hbp1.Date_Due, hbp1.Unit_Price
FROM Historical_Buy_Prices AS hbp1 
Left JOIN Historical_Buy_Prices AS hpb2 
    ON (hbp1.SKU = hpb2.SKU) 
    AND (hbp1.Date_Due + 1 = hpb2.Date_Due)
WHERE (hpb2.Date_Due IS NULL
    OR hbp1.Unit_Price <> hbp2.Unit_Price)
ORDER BY hbp1.SKU, hbp1.Date_Due;
```

When I run it, before showing the results, Access prompts me for the value of hbp2.Unit_Price, and then still returns duplicates.

I'm sure it's something simple that I missed.  Can you please assist?  Thanks,

Updated:
To create the table using ddl, use:

```
 CREATE TABLE Historical_Buy_Prices (SKU Text, UNIT_PRICE Currency, DATE_DUE Date
);
```

To insert the sample data, use:

```
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1200NBACSTA", 13.00, #11/2/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1200NBACSTA", 13.00, #10/19/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1200NBACSTA", 13.00, #9/28/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1200NBACSTA", 10.50, #9/21/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1200NBACSTA", 13.00, #8/27/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1200NBACSTA", 13.00, #7/4/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1200NBACSTA", 12.50, #6/19/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1700NDACSTA", 14.50, #10/27/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1700NDACSTA", 14.73, #9/29/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1700NDACSTA", 14.73, #8/23/2012#);
INSERT INTO Historical_Buy_Prices VALUES ("BHM1700NDACSTA", 14.50, #6/20/2012#);
```

Comment: you get faster response to such question if you provide the create table and insert statements in your question...

Comment: How should that make it easier to answer?

Comment: Thanks, Mitch.  I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: I just looked at your data, and your sample input does not correspond to your expected output.

Comment: Can there ever be more than 1 row per SKU per DATE_DUE?

Comment: Mitch, I looked it over again and I don't see any issue.  What did you find wrong with my expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below uses a subquery (aliased as "sub") which in turn uses a correlated subquery to determine the previous price for each `SKU` and `DATE_DUE` pair.  The outermost query filters out the rows you're not interested in.

You can break out the "sub" subquery as a separate query to help understand how it works.

```
SELECT
    sub.SKU,
    sub.UNIT_PRICE,
    sub.DATE_DUE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            h.SKU,
            h.DATE_DUE,
            h.UNIT_PRICE,
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 UNIT_PRICE
                FROM Historical_Buy_Prices
                WHERE
                        SKU = h.SKU
                    AND DATE_DUE < h.DATE_DUE
                ORDER BY DATE_DUE DESC
            ) AS previous_price
        FROM Historical_Buy_Prices AS h
    ) AS sub
WHERE
       sub.UNIT_PRICE <> [previous_price]
    OR sub.previous_price Is Null
ORDER BY
    sub.SKU,
    sub.DATE_DUE DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'm getting: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."

Comment: I tested that query in Access 2007 with the sample data you provided.  It returned the result set you asked for with no error message.  I don't understand how you can get that error with only one row for each SKU plus DATE_DUE combination ... which is what you told us to assume.

Comment: I looked at it again.  It was a glitch on my end.  It now works as I had asked.  Thanks again.